# Java. Странное поведение методов totalMemory() и freeMemory()

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо узнать сколько памяти занимает мой объект, и я делаю это так:

Сам объект:

```
public class DemoGC {
    private String fieldOne = "abc";
    private String fieldTwo = "cba";
}
```

Его замер делаю так:

```
    public static long memoryState() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        return runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long before = memoryState();

        DemoGC demoGC = new DemoGC();

        long after = memoryState();
        System.out.println(after - before);
    }
```

Сам объект явно не большой, всего пара строк... Но, на выходе мне печатает страшное число: `335568`. Даже учитывая что это размер в байтах, то откуда так много? Может я что-то не так делаю? Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Что я не так считаю?

Comment: По этой ссылке есть вся информация http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-are-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory

Comment: вам нужен [jol](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/)